# Slow down when searching through many elements using Jquery

Tags: jquery, performance

I have an html table which is hundreds of rows long that contains a list of strings.  I also have an input box that will insert new rows into the table. The second td element in each row is always a string within a div, so a row in the table might look like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="a_string" style="width:200px;">
        <div style="word-wrap:break-word;">hello world</div>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

I want to insert new rows into this table based on a list of strings from the user, if a string is already in the table it will be ignored and not inserted.  The problem arises when the list of strings from the user is very long and the number of rows in the table is very long, the hastily written method i am using to check for duplicates is much too inefficient for this task:

```
function check_rows(item) { //called on each item in input list
    var tf = false;
    $('#mytable tbody').children().each(function (i) {
        //loop through each tr

        if ($('#mytable tbody').children().eq(i).children().eq(1).hasClass('a_string')) {
            //if the row is a string to compare (second td element has the class 'a_string')

            if (item == $('#mytable tbody').children().eq(i).children().eq(1).children().eq(0).html()) {
                //find the string within the div within second td in row "i" (current indexed row)
                //compare the strings and if it is found in the table break out of the loop

                tf = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    //if the item is not found in any of the rows false will be returned 
    return tf;
}
```

The function does what it is supposed to do (check for duplicate strings), it is just way too slow.  I tried to insert the list without this function and it was almost instantaneous, so the problem is here.

Any suggestions on how to to improve this function would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$('#mytable tbody')` is being called too many times. Have you tried storing a reference?. Can you keep track of a list of items in an array instead of checking it from DOM?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes i could, i didn't think this would have an effect at all.  I have not been concerned with jquery execution speed since it hasn't mattered until now.  Would storing a reference to tbody and keeping an array of the items in the table improve my performance at all?

Comment: There's too much DOM traversal, this is a little bit better -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsu5c/), but not much?

Comment: @adeneo this doesn't work because the object reference from the each loop does not support jquery functions.

Comment: @WillSampson - say what now? Of course it does, if you wrap it with jQuery, it's just a regular JS DOM referrence!

Comment: @adeneo you're right!, i was calling it like elem. not $(elem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code. You don't have to use `$('#mytable tbody')` inside `each`. Instead use `this`.

Try to assign elements to a variable and it will create a reference which will be much faster.

```
function check_rows(item) { //called on each item in input list
    var tf = false;
    $('#mytable tbody').children().each(function (i) {
        //loop through each tr

        var tr = $(this).eq(i).children();    
        if (tr.eq(1).hasClass('a_string')) {
            //if the row is a string to compare (second td element has the class 'a_string')

            if (item == tr.eq(1).eq(0).html()) {
                //find the string within the div within second td in row "i" (current indexed row)
                //compare the strings and if it is found in the table break out of the loop

                tf = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    //if the item is not found in any of the rows false will be returned 
    return tf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you're going to be doing a bunch of DOM searches of the same material, then you probably want to make a copy of the relevant data into a javascript data structure that is much, much faster to search than traversing the DOM every time.

If you're checking for exact matches on strings, you can even use the indexing powers of a javascript object to give you a very quick yes/no answer on whether an exact string is already in your data structure or not.  This should be orders of magnitude faster than a linear search through the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would use selectors like this

```
function check_rows(item) { //called on each item in input list
    var tf = false,
        mytbody = $('#mytable tbody'),
        secondCell;
    $('tr', mytbody).each(function (i) {
        //loop through each tr
        secondCell = $('td', this).eq(1);
        if (secondCell.hasClass('a_string')) {
            //if the row is a string to compare (second td element has the class 'a_string')

            if (item == $('div:first', secondCell).html()) {
                //find the string within the div within second td in row "i" (current indexed row)
                //compare the strings and if it is found in the table break out of the loop

                tf = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    //if the item is not found in any of the rows false will be returned 
    return tf;
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me how the selector `$('div:first', secondCell)` works?

Comment: it seems that it doesn't like the definition of `secondCell`

Comment: It's a child selector, try this then `secondCell = $('td:eq(1)', this)`